# How To Run Two Models In Parallel On Two Different GPUs In Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to do a grid search for parameters on neural nets.  I have two GPUs, and I would like to run one model on the first GPU, and another model with different parameters on the second GPU.  A first attempt that doesn't work goes like this:

```python
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    model_1 = sequential()
    model_1.add(embedding) // the embeddings are defined earlier in the code
    model_1.add(LSTM(50))
    model_1.add(Dense(5, activation = 'softmax'))
    model_1.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam')
    model_1.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs = 15, batch_size = 15)
with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
    model_2 = sequential()
    model_2.add(embedding)
    model_2.add(LSTM(100))
    model_2.add(Dense(5, activation = 'softmax'))
    model_2.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam')
    model_2.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs = 15, batch_size = 15)
```

Edit:  I ran my code again and did not get an error.  However, the two models run sequentially rather than in parallel.  Is it possible to do multithreading here?  That is my next attempt.

There is a lot of discussion online about using multiple GPUs with keras, but when it comes to running multiple models simultaneously, the discussion is limited to running multiple models on a single GPU.  The discussion regarding multiple GPUs is also limited to data parallelization and device parallelization.  I don't believe I want to do either since I am not trying to break up a single model to run on multiple gpus.  Is it possible to run two separate models simultaneously in keras with two GPUs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to this problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322698/tensorflow-keras-multi-threaded-model-fitting?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).  However, the softmax activation function runs on the CPU only as of now.  It is necessary to direct the cpu to perform the dense layer:

```
with tf.device('cpu:0')
```

Switching between the cpu and the gpu does not seem cause noticeable slow down.  With LSTM's though, it may be best to run the entire model on the cpu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multi_gpu_model` (reference [here](https://keras.io/utils/#multi_gpu_model))

Define your model first

```python
model = sequential()
model.add(embedding) // the embeddings are defined earlier in the code
model.add(LSTM(50))
model.add(Dense(5, activation = 'softmax'))
```

and the create a `multi_gpu_model` with 2 GPUs:

```python
parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=2)
```

This will work if you want to divide the input and process it on 2 GPUs. It will not cover your use case of having two different models on two GPUs though.

Comment: I would be ok with this, but the parallel_model is slower, it does not provide speed up.  I think it is because the model is so small there is no benefit.

Answer (score -3):

Because your code is in sequential. You can try threading to run 2 blocks in parallel. Google "python multithreading" will help you to get lots of examples.

Comment: While this might be an answer to the question, it's generalized to the point where it may as well be a comment instead. You should [edit] your answer to include some more context or include some example code specific to the question being asked.