# Train multiple keras/tensorflow models on different GPUs simultaneously

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I would like to train multiple models on multiple GPUs at the simultaneously from within a jupyter notebook. I am working on a node with 4GPUs. I would like to assign one GPU to one model and train 4 different models at the same time. Right now, I select a GPU for one notebook by (e.g.):

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '1'

def model(...):
    ....

model.fit(...)
```

In four different notebooks. Though, then the results and the output of the fitting procedure is distributed in four different notebooks. Though, running them in one notebook sequentially, needs a lot of time. How do you assign GPU's to individual functions and run them in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Tensorflow scopes like so:

```
with tf.device_scope('/gpu:0'):
  model1.fit()
with tf.device_scope('/gpu:1'):
  model2.fit()
with tf.device_scope('/gpu:2'):
  model3.fit()
```

Comment: This does NOT run them parallel, only sequentially on different GPUs, right?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this is sequential. I believe the right answer is something closer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322698/tensorflow-keras-multi-threaded-model-fitting?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: just an add-on question. One might be tempted to use multiple threads, one for each model. In that case, would python's GIL prevent the realization of concurrency?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to train models on different cloud GPUs (e.g. GPU instances from AWS), try this library:

```
!pip install aibro==0.0.45 --extra-index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple

from aibro.train import fit
machine_id = 'g4dn.4xlarge' #instance name on AWS
job_id, trained_model, history = fit(
    model=model,
    train_X=train_X,
    train_Y=train_Y,
    validation_data=(validation_X, validation_Y),
    machine_id=machine_id
)
```

Tutorial: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19sXZ4kbic681zqEsrl_CZfB5cegUwuIB#scrollTo=ERqoHEaamR1Y